# Better method for checking between two items in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, angularjs

I have an array like so:

```
var data = [
    {
        "title" : "Title 1",
        "slideText" : "",
        "startTime" : 0
    },
    {
        "title" : "Title 2",
        "slideText" : "",
        "startTime" : 60
    },
    {
        "title" : "Title 3",
        "slideText" : "",
        "startTime" : 120
    }
];
```

I have a `seeked` event listener on an HTML5 video. When a user seeks, I need to check where they are at and determine which index in the array they're on. For example, they seek to 72 seconds, they would be on array[1]

Right now I have this:

```
player.addEventListener("seeked", function(event)
{
    currentTime = player.currentTime;
    angular.forEach($scope.data, function(value, key)
    {
        if (currentTime >= $scope.data[key].startTime && currentTime <= $scope.data[key + 1].startTime)
        {
            $scope.$apply(function()
            {
                $scope.setActive(key);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

That all works until the seeked time reaches the end of the array and `$scope.data[key + 1].time` is undefined. How should I approach this? My mind isn't on track right now and I still haven't had my coffee :|

**edit**

new function working

```
player.addEventListener("seeked", function(event)
{
    currentTime = player.currentTime;
    for (var i = 0; i <= $scope.data.length; i++)
    {
        if ($scope.data[i + 1] != undefined)
        {
            if (currentTime < $scope.data[i + 1].startTime)
            {
                $scope.$apply(function()
                {
                    $scope.setActive(i);
                });
                break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $scope.$apply(function()
            {
                $scope.setActive($scope.data.length - 1);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Add an end time variable, then you don't need to do a [key + 1] check. That will always error on the last element.

Comment: that is what I wanted to avoid. It is certainly an option and I guess I could generate the property programatically. These arrays are generated elsewhere and given to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a check for `[key + 1]` to ensure you don't try to access an element beyond the length of the array.

```
player.addEventListener("seeked", function(event)
{
    currentTime = player.currentTime;
    angular.forEach($scope.data, function(value, key)
    {
        if ( ($scope.data[key+1] != undefined) && currentTime < $scope.data[key+1].startTime)
        {
           // this is the one we are after
           return false; // exit foreach
        } else {
          // we are on the last one.
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: every time I seek, I am landing in the else part of this. I think maybe because it still loops even when the first part is true

Comment: @Ronnie yes it will, I added a return statement to exit the loop.

Comment: I tried that...apparently `angular.forEach` doesn't support this sort of thing https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/263 I need to rethink this

Comment: @Ronnie re-write the loop as a plain foreach. It will be a bit faster and easier to implement this logic.

Comment: yep I am in the process of doing that. `break` or `return false` still isn't exiting the loop. Every time I seek, I see the `setActive` fn get called as well as 'last' in the console. I updated my question

Answer (score 2):

Test for the array element's existence first. If it fails, the other tests will be ignored:

```
if ($scope.data[key+1] && currentTime>=$scope.data[key].startTime && currentTime<=$scope.data[key+1].startTime)
```

Comment: This gets rid of the error, but I still need to know that I am on the last element. Say I seek to 130 and the start time of the last element is 120. I still need to be notified I am on the last element

Comment: Then run a separate standalone test for `if ($scope.data[key+1])` or `if ($scope.data.length<=key)`. Or stop using `angular.forEach` and construct a basic `for` loop of your own that stops at `$scope.data.length-2`. There are many ways to do it.

Comment: Its the [key+1] that is causing the issue. On the last item, key + 1 is always undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Here was the final solution that worked

```
player.addEventListener("seeked", function(event)
{
    currentTime = player.currentTime;
    for (var i = 0; i <= $scope.data.length; i++)
    {
        if ($scope.data[i + 1] != undefined)
        {
            if (currentTime < $scope.data[i + 1].startTime)
            {
                $scope.$apply(function()
                {
                    $scope.setActive(i);
                });
                break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $scope.$apply(function()
            {
                $scope.setActive(i - 1);
            });
        }
    }
});
```